# Granting access on console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, xna-4.0

I have an xna application and second application which is .net Console and can delete and replace the content directory of the main app during runtime. The problem is that the console cannot delete the content because it has no access. How can I grant it access?

Comment: The questio is unclear. I'll guess that you want to delete something from Program Files. You can't and shouldn't, with good reason. Files in Program Files aren't writeable to prevent malware, users and improperly coded applications from damaging application files. Writeable data should be placed in an application's ProgramData folder

Comment: No it is not in program files it is in d:/. And it can delete everything except the Content folder of an xna application which I am developing. The content is in "Content/Content" and the console application is placed in "/Console"

Comment: Then post the details. It's impossible to help otherwise. What access are you talking about? Did you receive an error message? What was it? Is D your system drive perhaps? You need elevated priviledges to write the roor folder of a system drive.

Comment: D is not my system drive the error is access denied exception. I think the access is denied because it is content for an xna application and that is the reason there is no access.

Comment: Please post the relevant code that gives the error. As it is, it's just a guessing game and that's not how SO works :)

Comment: So I now am extracting the files to AppData/Roaming by ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("archivedir", directory) in which directory is string variable and leads to AppData/Roaming/Eclipse (Eclipse is my application name). It works. The problems come that I can't delete it by File.Delete(Path.Combine(directory, "Content"))     (Content is the name of the folder I am trying to delete and it is placed in AppData/Roaming/Eclipse ). The app is not installed and maybe that is the problem. The exception I receive while trying to delete Content is access denied exception.